# Which module should I require in Java 9 to use JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, java-9, module-info

I'm testing Java 9 with a project which requires JPA (`javax.persistence.*` classes). When I add the `module-info.java` and declare my module, all classes under `javax.persistece` package become unavailable.

I searched a lot, but I couldn't find the module to require to use JPA in a Java 9 module project.

**UPDATE**
As Alan suggested, I ran

```
$ jar --describe-module --file=javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar

No module descriptor found. Derived automatic module.

java.persistence@2.2 automatic
requires java.base mandated
contains javax.persistence
contains javax.persistence.criteria
contains javax.persistence.metamodel
contains javax.persistence.spi
```

But still with this `module-info.java`

```
module my.module {

    requires java.persistence;

}
```

I get "module-info.java:[3,18] module not found: java.persistence".

**UPDATE 2**
This is my project structure:

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   ├── my
    │   │   │   └── module
    │   │   │       └── MyBean.java
    │   │   └── module-info.java
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        ├── java
        └── resources
```

The `pom.xml` has the `javax.persistence-api` dependency.

Testing repo: https://github.com/heruan/java9-jpa

Comment: `requires` should use the file name for automatic modules: `javax.persistence-api-2.2` but that looks weird. I would rename the jar?

Comment: @JoopEggen The automatic module naming if I am not wrong, converts any non-alphanumeric  character into a dot(`.`). So the current module name would end up being `javax.persistence.api` in that case(ofcourse without version number which are not maintained at module level)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), you can use a dependency like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

with `maven-compiler-plugin` as updated to work with jdk9 [detailed here.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html)

Similar with dependency with [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle)

```
compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'
```

which is based out of the [javaee/jpa-spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec). This would facilitate the

```
requires java.persistence
```

as an automatic module as proposed to be the name intended for the module [here.](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/issues/145)

---

Adding to the details, this is defined in the ***META-INF/MANIFEST.MF*** as :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Description: Java(TM) Persistence 2.2 API jar
Automatic-Module-Name: java.persistence
...
```

***Note***- The way to figure out the module name as suggested by Alan is precise, but no advertising and I still prefer using a class of some package and then let IntelliJ(2017.2.4) do that resolution for me when I say 'import class' and then 'add requires'. ;)

Comment: Thank you, but I already have that dependency in my `pom.xml`.

Comment: @GiovanniLovato the name of the module you tried is incorrect though

Comment: Corrected, but still "module not found: java.persistence".

Comment: Not sure of what your project structure looks like. Just make sure that the jar is available on the module path in that case.

Comment: Updated question with project structure! Don't know if Maven dependencies are included in module path.

Comment: The structure looks fine to me. Can you share the relevant pom.xml as well and does the project build with maven(if you tried)?

Comment: Repo at https://github.com/heruan/java9-jpa (Maven fails with "module not found: java.persistence").

Comment: @GiovanniLovato Fails for me for one reason.. takes the deault `maven-compiler-plugin 3.1` which doesn't support jdk9. So try modifying the plugin as [mentioned here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html)

Comment: Forcing Maven compiler to 3.7.0 solved the issue compiling in Maven, not in Eclipse though—but that's an Eclipse issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that JPA has been published as a module yet but you should be able to use it as an automatic module. Can you use `jar --file=<jarfile> --describe-module` to see what module name is derived for the JPA JAR file.

Comment: The jar tool report its name as "java.persistence", not "javax.persistence".

Comment: Corrected, but still "module not found: java.persistence".

Comment: Hmm, I expected it would work, at least with maven-compiler-plugin 3.6.2 which invokes the compiler with the right module path when compiling a module.

Comment: Just saw your comment with the maven project on github. If you update the pom to use maven-compiler-plugin 3.6.2 or newer as the build plugin then you should find that it builds okay.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```